# PsService.exe Operation Process Profiling - 20 second delay

Tags: window, psexec

On server1, I am executing

`PsService.exe -accepteula \\server2 stop "Name of Service"`

The process is successful, but there is a 20 second delay.  I ran Process Monitor on server1 and server2.  On server1 I found PsService.exe was Process Profiling for 20 seconds.  Server2 did not receive the request to stop the service until the Process Profiling was complete.

Here is a screenshot from server1

[image]

What is Process Profiling?  How can I remove the delay from PsService?

Comment: I know this is old, but I was observing the same sort of behavior and thought I would add some information: I was seeing the same "Process Profiling" once per second in process monitor for a program that was hanging during network connection code. I made a program that I coded to intentionally become non-responsive and did not use the network at all and I observed the same "Process Profiling" events once per second. So I believe that those events are not a *cause* for the delay, but are instead happening *because of* the delay and the delay has some other cause.

Comment: Ok, nevermind what I said above...I just realized that the "Process Profiling" probably has nothing at all do to with the delay. If you filter for only the profiling events in procmon, the "Process Profiling" events just happen about every 1second, it's just that they are noticeable during a time when the process is doing nothing else because there is nothing else in the log...