# How to disable the "Process Profiling" Operation when Excel is Saving or Calculating

Tags: process

I am working with very large Excel Workbooks; Worksheets with 400,000 rows.

During the Save and Calculation operations Excel Enters a (Not Responding) mode for hours sometimes.
This is a new issue it started 2 days ago.

Here is what I am seeing in Sysinternals Process Monitor.
[image]

So does anyone know:

1. What the Process Profiling Operation is used for
2. Is there a way to disable it or configure it?

I can not get my work done.

I did see the same type of Question ask 10 years ago relating to PsService.exe
[PsService.exe Operation Process Profiling - 20 second delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411767/psservice-exe-operation-process-profiling-20-second-delay)

I would appreciate any help.

I do not know what to try.
I can't find any technical references to the "Process Profiling" operation.

Comment: Just as described in the question you linked, it seems to me that the "Process Profiling" event is generated by default once per second for any running process. For me, it is filtered out by default ("Filter -> Filter... -> Reset" creates exactly one filter, which is "Exclude if event class is Profiling", in v3.01). I don't think this is in any way connected to your Excel problems.

Answer (score -1):

.Folks,
It cost me $2000 in billable time but I figured what the issue was.
It was an Update by Microsoft to:
Microsoft (MS) 365 Apps for Business had been updated (16.0.16731.20…)
I did a system Restore back to 28 Aug 2023 and it all disappeared.
MS introduced Operations that did the following:

1. Process Profiling as seen in the Pic above.
2. Windsock – TCP Events
3. ReadFile Email

These killed the performance of Excel.
and contributed to corruption of the data in the Excel Workbooks.
I have added the Event detail produced by Process Monitor below.
So watch out for this.
Regards
Scott

**WindSock - TCP Details Connect to an Azure Server 104.208.16.88**

4:13:37.2941701 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    RegSetValue HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\ClientTelemetry\RulesMetadata\excel.exe\ULSMonitor\ULSAllCategories  SUCCESS Type: REG_SZ, Length: 10, Data: 10,6
4:13:37.2942625 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    RegCloseKey HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\ClientTelemetry\RulesMetadata\excel.exe\ULSMonitor   SUCCESS
4:13:42.6786022 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    RegQueryValue   HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\WinSock2\Parameters\Protocol_Catalog9\Serial_Access_Num  SUCCESS Type: REG_DWORD, Length: 4, Data: 12
4:13:42.6786921 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    RegQueryKey HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\WinSock2\Parameters\Protocol_Catalog9    SUCCESS Query: HandleTags, HandleTags: 0x0
4:13:42.6787885 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    RegOpenKey  HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\WinSock2\Parameters\Protocol_Catalog9\0000000C   REPARSE Desired Access: Read
4:13:42.6788602 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    RegOpenKey  HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\WinSock2\Parameters\Protocol_Catalog9\0000000C   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read
4:13:42.7175158 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    TCP Connect Capus-1e_7770.routeree62d4.com:50400 -> 104.208.16.88:https SUCCESS Length: 0, mss: 1400, sackopt: 1, tsopt: 0, wsopt: 0, rcvwin: 65535, rcvwinscale: 0
4:13:42.7553256 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    TCP Receive Capus-1e_7770.routeree62d4.com:50400 -> 104.208.16.88:https SUCCESS Length: 0, seqnum: 0, connid: 0
4:13:42.7559528 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    TCP Disconnect  Capus-1e_7770.routeree62d4.com:50400 -> 104.208.16.88:https SUCCESS Length: 0, seqnum: 0, connid: 0
4:13:42.7951853 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    TCP Connect Capus-1e_7770.routeree62d4.com:50401 -> 104.208.16.88:https SUCCESS Length: 0, mss: 1400, sackopt: 1, tsopt: 0, wsopt: 1, rcvwin: 262144, rcvwinscale: 8
4:13:42.8460541 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    TCP Send    Capus-1e_7770.routeree62d4.com:50401 -> 104.208.16.88:https SUCCESS Length: 227, startime: 442861, endtime: 442867, seqnum: 0, connid: 0
4:13:42.8462287 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    TCP TCPCopy Capus-1e_7770.routeree62d4.com:50401 -> 104.208.16.88:https SUCCESS Length: 1400, seqnum: 0, connid: 0
4:13:42.8462655 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    TCP Receive Capus-1e_7770.routeree62d4.com:50401 -> 104.208.16.88:https SUCCESS Length: 1400, seqnum: 0, connid: 0
4:13:42.8463601 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    TCP TCPCopy Capus-1e_7770.routeree62d4.com:50401 -> 104.208.16.88:https SUCCESS Length: 1400, seqnum: 0, connid: 0
4:13:42.8463721 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    TCP TCPCopy Capus-1e_7770.routeree62d4.com:50401 -> 104.208.16.88:https SUCCESS Length: 3495, seqnum: 0, connid: 0
4:13:42.8464107 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    TCP Receive Capus-1e_7770.routeree62d4.com:50401 -> 104.208.16.88:https SUCCESS Length: 4895, seqnum: 0, connid: 0
4:13:42.8971103 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    TCP Send    Capus-1e_7770.routeree62d4.com:50401 -> 104.208.16.88:https SUCCESS Length: 158, startime: 442868, endtime: 442872, seqnum: 0, connid: 0
4:13:42.8971427 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    TCP TCPCopy Capus-1e_7770.routeree62d4.com:50401 -> 104.208.16.88:https SUCCESS Length: 51, seqnum: 0, connid: 0
4:13:42.8971663 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    TCP Receive Capus-1e_7770.routeree62d4.com:50401 -> 104.208.16.88:https SUCCESS Length: 51, seqnum: 0, connid: 0
4:13:42.9377959 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    TCP Send    Capus-1e_7770.routeree62d4.com:50401 -> 104.208.16.88:https SUCCESS Length: 857, startime: 442872, endtime: 442876, seqnum: 0, connid: 0
4:13:42.9378289 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    TCP Send    Capus-1e_7770.routeree62d4.com:50401 -> 104.208.16.88:https SUCCESS Length: 1332, startime: 442872, endtime: 442876, seqnum: 0, connid: 0
4:13:42.9400874 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    TCP TCPCopy Capus-1e_7770.routeree62d4.com:50401 -> 104.208.16.88:https SUCCESS Length: 452, seqnum: 0, connid: 0
4:13:42.9401132 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    TCP Receive Capus-1e_7770.routeree62d4.com:50401 -> 104.208.16.88:https SUCCESS Length: 452, seqnum: 0, connid: 0
4:13:42.9549145 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    RegQueryKey HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office  SUCCESS Query: HandleTags, HandleTags: 0x0
4:13:42.9550384 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\Common\ClientTelemetry\ViewerSettings    NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read/Write
4:13:42.9554812 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    LockFile    C:\Users\lcsdoc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\OTele\excel.exe.db-shm   SUCCESS Exclusive: False, Offset: 124, Length: 1, Fail Immediately: True
4:13:42.9555384 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    LockFile    C:\Users\lcsdoc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\OTele\excel.exe.db-shm   SUCCESS Exclusive: True, Offset: 120, Length: 1, Fail Immediately: True
4:13:42.9556265 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    UnlockFileSingle    C:\Users\lcsdoc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\OTele\excel.exe.db-shm   SUCCESS Offset: 120, Length: 1
4:13:42.9556628 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    UnlockFileSingle    C:\Users\lcsdoc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\OTele\excel.exe.db-shm   SUCCESS Offset: 124, Length: 1
4:13:43.2948358 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    Thread Exit     SUCCESS Thread ID: 5504, User Time: 0.0468750, Kernel Time: 0.7500000

**ReadFile Email**

4:17:28.6221401 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    ReadFile    D:\Outlook Data Files\scott.morrison@capusgroup.com - srmorrison@earthlink.net.ost  SUCCESS Offset: 0, Length: 4, Priority: Normal
4:17:28.6224533 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    FlushBuffersFile    D:\Outlook Data Files\scott.morrison@capusgroup.com - srmorrison@earthlink.net.ost  SUCCESS
4:17:28.6294043 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    WriteFile   D:\Outlook Data Files\scott.morrison@capusgroup.com - srmorrison@earthlink.net.ost  SUCCESS Offset: 0, Length: 4, Priority: Normal
4:17:28.6295034 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    FlushBuffersFile    D:\Outlook Data Files\scott.morrison@capusgroup.com - srmorrison@earthlink.net.ost  SUCCESS
4:17:28.6295444 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    WriteFile   D:\Outlook Data Files\scott.morrison@capusgroup.com - srmorrison@earthlink.net.ost  SUCCESS Offset: 0, Length: 4,096, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
4:17:28.6323807 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    WriteFile   D:\Outlook Data Files\scott.morrison@capusgroup.com - srmorrison@earthlink.net.ost  SUCCESS Offset: 0, Length: 531, Priority: Normal
4:17:28.6324464 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    FlushBuffersFile    D:\Outlook Data Files\scott.morrison@capusgroup.com - srmorrison@earthlink.net.ost  SUCCESS
4:17:28.6324807 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    WriteFile   D:\Outlook Data Files\scott.morrison@capusgroup.com - srmorrison@earthlink.net.ost  SUCCESS Offset: 0, Length: 4,096, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
4:17:28.6350270 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    FlushBuffersFile    D:\Outlook Data Files\scott.morrison@capusgroup.com - srmorrison@earthlink.net.ost  SUCCESS
4:17:28.6358271 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    UnlockFileSingle    D:\Outlook Data Files\scott.morrison@capusgroup.com - srmorrison@earthlink.net.ost  SUCCESS Offset: 532, Length: 1
4:17:28.6367735 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    Thread Exit     SUCCESS Thread ID: 6308, User Time: 0.0000000, Kernel Time: 0.0000000
4:17:28.6376864 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    CloseFile   D:\Outlook Data Files~scott.morrison@capusgroup.com - srmorrison@earthlink.net.ost.tmp SUCCESS
4:17:28.6380578 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    CreateFile  D:\Outlook Data Files~scott.morrison@capusgroup.com - srmorrison@earthlink.net.ost.tmp SUCCESS Desired Access: Read Attributes, Delete, Disposition: Open, Options: Non-Directory File, Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
4:17:28.6381993 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    QueryAttributeTagFile   D:\Outlook Data Files~scott.morrison@capusgroup.com - srmorrison@earthlink.net.ost.tmp SUCCESS Attributes: HAT, ReparseTag: 0x0
4:17:28.6382550 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    SetDispositionInformationEx D:\Outlook Data Files~scott.morrison@capusgroup.com - srmorrison@earthlink.net.ost.tmp SUCCESS Flags: FILE_DISPOSITION_DELETE, FILE_DISPOSITION_POSIX_SEMANTICS
4:17:28.6383255 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    CloseFile   D:\Outlook Data Files~scott.morrison@capusgroup.com - srmorrison@earthlink.net.ost.tmp SUCCESS
4:17:28.6389297 PM  EXCEL.EXE   3960    CloseFile   D:\Outlook Data Files\scott.morrison@capusgroup.com - srmorrison@earthlink.net.ost  SUCCESS